# Angular Lazy Loaded module dependencies (Encountered undefined provider)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have a **core**, **shared** and many **features modules** in an Angular 5 app. Each of these features modules are lazy loaded.

Almost all of them have dependencies on each other. As an example, I have a lazy loaded **message** module that depends on another lazily loaded module (not core, not shared) for resolving route data.

When I compile the app with `yarn start`, everything works fine. Though, when I try to build the app with `ng build --prod` and the AOT kicks in, I'm getting the following error :

> ERROR in: Encountered undefined provider! Usually, this means you have a circular dependency (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.

What bugs me is the fact that no circular dependencies are flagged on build time.

If I build the app without AOT, with `ng build --no-aot --prod`, I'm getting no error and everything works fine.

I tried to eject the app from the angular CLI to directly build the app with the webpack task, but with no result or detail on what's happening.

Where do I start to debug this problem?

I'm using a lot of barrel files in my app. Each of them has a similar structure like this (*style borrowed from Todd Motto's NGRX course*) :

```
import { AlertsComponent } from '@alerts/containers/alerts/alerts.component';
import { AlertComponent } from '@alerts/containers/alert/alert.component';

export const containers: Array<any> = [AlertsComponent, AlertComponent];

export * from '@alerts/containers/alerts/alerts.component';
export * from '@alerts/containers/alert/alert.component';
```

And these containers are spread in the module like this :

```
import * as fromAlertsContainers from '@alerts/containers';
import * as fromCoreGuards from '@core/guards';

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), SharedModule, CommonModule],
    providers: [...fromCoreGuards.guards],
    declarations: [...fromAlertsContainers.containers],
    exports: [...fromAlertsContainers.containers]
})
export class AlertsModule {}
```

I'm a doing something wrong ? Why does it work with `yarn start` and not with `ng build --prod`?

> **Testing #1 : using forwardRef as a patch.**

Currently testing the following solution, I'll keep you in touch if it works/fix the problem :

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => ApiService))
private apiService: ApiService
```

> **Solution!**

Here is how I fixed the problem.

1. Removed all the `providers` from the AppModule.
2. Reinserting each of them one by one.
3. After each insert, I ran `ng build --prod` then waited for the build result.
4. It turns out, I had the following code that caused the circular

   dependency :
    providers: [
     Location,
      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthTokenInterceptor,
        multi: true
      }
   ]

`PathLocationStrategy` needed `Location` and `Location` needed `PathLocationStrategy`.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Ionic 3 & Angular 5.

Comment: Do you know any way to output a verbose log of the build command ? I.E., what's happening behind the scenes ?

Comment: Dunno yet... I had two ngModules wroten by my self, they all work without any problem with JIT mode, but can not compile with AOT. 
https://github.com/Chatie/db/issues/30
https://github.com/zixia/auth-angular/issues/1

Comment: Have you tried to eject the project from the CLI and build it with an NPM task directly ?

Comment: What I did is use the npm script from ionic: `npm run ionic:build --prod`

Comment: Is your app using barrels (index.ts) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using barrels everywhere. I found I can fix this by not using barrels. However, I want to find out why it does not work with my barrels.  I have an issue to track this problem at https://github.com/Chatie/db/issues/30

Comment: Even though I'm using barrels too, I've removed all the barrels and I'm still getting the error. I'm out of resources.

Comment: Don't give up! Do you have any repo that could reproduce this issue easily? I might be able to have a look for you if you want to.